# How do ubuntu software center sort out packages dependencies problem?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, vlc, source

How do ubuntu software center sort out packages dependencies problem ?like vlc player package? Because when i tried to build vlc with source it have many dependencies and each dependency have further dependencies....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VLC package specifies which dependencies necessary and the `apt-get` command installs all packages required to fulfill these.

When building from source that can be a tedious manual task. That's why there are source packages that should ensure the dependencies for building are met.

Comment: Did that answer help you in same way, Jagjot?